# How to increase the height of a button using animation?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-cascades

Could someone let me know how to animate how to increase the height of a button?
I can increase the height of a button on the click of another button

```
Page {
    Container {
             Button {
                    id: btn2
                    text: "button2"

                    onClicked: {
                         btn1.maxHeight = 500
                         btn1.minHeight = 500
                    }
             }

             ImageButton {
                         id: btn1
                         defaultImageSource: "asset:///image.png"
             }
         }
   }
```

But how do I animate the button increasing in height?

Thanks